# Consider the ellipsoid $3x^2+2y^2+z^2=18$. Find all the points where the tangent plane to this ellipsoid is parallel to the plane $6x−2y+2z=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hello I am not too sure how to solve this would really appreciate some help:

Consider the ellipsoid $3x^2+2y^2+z^2=18$. Find all the points where the tangent plane to this ellipsoid is parallel to the plane $6x−2y+2z=0$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: "I am not too sure " says you tried some thing? So tell us what you know of tangent plans

Comment: Gradient of the ellipsoid must be a multiple of the normal vector of the plane....